# Updating variable values when running a thread using QThread in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, python-multithreading, qthread

So problem occurred when I tried using `Threading` in my code. What I want to do is passing default values to the `def __init__` and then calling the thread with its instance with updated values but somehow I cannot get the updated values.
 Below is my initial code: **main.py**

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import GUI # GUI app by using PYQT4
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThread
#import Photos

class PyMain(QtGui.QWidget, GUI.Ui_Pycloud):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)

        """Picking up data from GUI.py file where initially,
        it is set to 'Username' and 'Password' respectively.
        and initialising `GetThread` class"""
        self.get_thread = GetThread(str(self.username.text()), 
                                    str(self.password.text())
                                   )
        """This is what I was initially using.
           I have tried, only passing the instance and calling 
           get_thread.start() inside __init__ fn but even if i don't click 
           `commandLinkButton` it is somehow called automatically.
           I know it is not the right approach"""
        self.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(self.get_thread.start)


class GetThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def authentication(self):
        print self.username, self.password
        # user = Photos.PyPhotos(self.username, self.password)
        # user.authentication(user)

    def run(self):
        self.authentication()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = PyMain()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Below is what I tried:

```
...........................
...........................
...........................

class PyMain(QtGui.QWidget, GUI.Ui_Pycloud):
  def __init__(self):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
    self.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(GetThread(str(self.username.text()), 
                                             str(self.password.text())).__init__)

class GetThread(QThread):

 def __init__(self, username, password):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.start()
...........................
...........................
...........................
```

**Result:** `Username Password`

> Which is shown the moment I run my `main.py` file, whereas I should get this only and only if I press `commandLinkButton` and should update variables if I update them on my GUI which is not happening.

**EDIT:** Below is what I tried again, it is showing me the correct output if I update them on GUI but threading is not working in this case:

```
..............
..............
..............
class PyMain(QtGui.QWidget, GUI.Ui_Pycloud):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(self.populate)

    def populate(self):
        get_thread = GetThread(str(self.username.text()), str(self.password.text()))
        get_thread.start()


class GetThread(QThread):

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def authentication(self):
        print self.username, self.password
        user = Photos.PyPhotos(self.username, self.password)
        user.authentication(user)

    def run(self):
        self.authentication()
......................
......................
......................
```

So anyone can please tell me how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a custom signal to send the authentication result back the main thread. But note that you *must not perform any gui operations of any kind* outside the main thread. So, for example, the worker thread cannot show an authentication dialog or attempt to directly update widgets. All it can do is execute a lengthy non-gui process and send the result back to the main thread when it's finished.

The basic structure of the code should look like this:

```
class PyMain(QtGui.QWidget, GUI.Ui_Pycloud):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.password.setEchoMode(QtGui.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.commandLinkButton.clicked.connect(self.populate)

    def populate(self):
        self.thread = GetThread(self.username.text(), self.password.text())
        self.thread.authResult.connect(self.handleAuthResult)
        self.thread.start()

    def handleAuthResult(self, result):
        # do something with result...

class GetThread(QThread):
    authResult = QtCore.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def authentication(self):
        result = do_authentication()
        self.authResult.emit(result)

    def run(self):
        self.authentication()
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly.
Kind of new to PyQt and threading, thank you for sharing that. (thumbs up) -
 @ekhumoro

Comment: and since we are on PyQt can you please suggest any post/blog for linking two different GUIs - @ekhumoro

Comment: @Aadit. You're welcome. I'm not sure what you mean by "linking two different GUIs". Maybe you should post a new question?

Comment: I just want to open instruction.py(Dialog window created by Qt designer) file on clicking a button on my main.py file. I have tried some approaches but running into problems.
So should I post this is a question?

Comment: @Aadit. Import the dialog class, and then create a subclass of it in the same way as `PyMain`. Then in a slot connected to the button, do `self.dialog = DialogSubClass(); self.dialog.show()`.

Comment: Just got that working thank you mate could not ask for more help thanks again @ekhumoro